# How can I find open source projects to contribute to (Ruby, Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, open-source

I'm a Ruby on Rails developer with a bit of time on my hands.

I would like to use this time to give back and learn by contributing to an open source project.

I'm not a top notch programmer and would like to start small.

Where can i find small open source projects in Ruby or Rails ? And how can I contribute ?

Alex

Comment: Related question on Programmers SE: [Need an idea for a non-rails ruby project!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/37816/need-an-idea-for-a-non-rails-ruby-project)

Comment: Here's one for you: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Brevidy

Comment: https://opensource-heroes.com/awesome/ruby is a list of the best projects, I think you can find good candidates of projects to which you can contribute.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

My advice is to look at the projects you use and really love, then get on their message boards and see what's needed. This is usually when people say "send me a pull request" or "send me a patch"

You can also look at a project's github "issues" tab. Any of these are generally something that can be worked on. You'll fork the project, make changes (and add tests), then send the maintainer a pull-request.

Anyway, long story short: *work on something you love using*.

Answer (score 7):

Not to forget [Github](http://github.com)

[A lot of Ruby and Rails projects on Github](https://github.com/search?q=language:ruby)

Answer (score 2):

Try to look on [gitorious](http://gitorious.org/search?q=category%3arails) or any other code hosting service